# Rendering Django Model to HTML

Tags: django, django-models

I made a Django app to fill my single html pages.
This is my model.py

```
class Flatpage(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=40)
    short_description_text = models.TextField(blank=True)
    content = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField('Published_Date')
    meta_keyword = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    meta_description = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

How should `views.py` look like to print the output of my model on the relevant pages?

How can I print my model output according to `slug` to single page htmls (About us, FAQ, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a basic use of Django models into html,
you must refer to the Django Documentation which is actually well explained:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/

If you don't have other issues after reading the docs please put the topics to solve.

Answer (score 0):

rendering models in views and other files is simple and well explained in the documentations of django. You should refer to that first and if not getting what you want in the documentations, I suggest you to refer some online tutorials and give it a try by yourself. That way you will learn better. I can simply tell you that for rendering your models in your views.py file, you first need to import those in the header using
from .models import ModelName
And then you need to use it by making particular functions for particular templates.